# passing a triple pointer into function then mallocing a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Getting a segmentation fault and don't understand why, have to pass in triple pointer for assignment so can't change that...

Here's the function

```
    void alloc2d(double*** a, int m, int n) {
     int i, j;

     **a  = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m);
     a[0] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * m);

     for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
      a[i] = (*a + n * i);
    }
```

Here's the calling of the function...

```
double** m;
alloc2d(&m, 5, 10);

double count = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        m[i][j] = ++count;

for (int i = 0; i <  5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%f ", m[i][j]);
```

Comment: That `alloc2d` function just looks... *wrong*!

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. Note that being a 3-star programmer in C is not a compliment: I always wonder why people insist of passing a pointer for a result, but make the function itself `void`.

Comment: @Olaf yeah.  I could mebbe understand if it returned an error number, but void?  Crazy.  TBH, I prefer to shove the pointers into suitably-labelled typdefs, (pMyStruct), and nested so as to be never more than 1 pointer deep.  Some devs don't like typedeffed pointers, well, I don't like '***' :)

Comment: @MartinJames `typedef`ing pointers is a strict no-go. That obfuscates the semantics and inhibits qualifying the pointee(!) e.g. `const`. Also, tha still is an N-star name. In C, a `typedef` is just an alias.

Comment: when you refereed to **a you de-referenced an uninitialized pointer (*a give you m), a[0] is an array of pointers, no doubles and you don't need j there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to allocate the the memory for the pointer where `a` refers to. Change `**a  = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m);` to `*a  = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m);`. You alraedy allocated the memory for `a[0]`, so start your loop with index `1`. The type of `a[0]` which is similar to `*a` is `double**`, but you want to set the pointer where `a[0]` refers to. Change `a[0]` to `(*a)[0]` and `a[i]` to `(*a)[i]`. Adapt your code like this:

```
void alloc2d(double*** a, int m, int n) {

     *a = malloc( sizeof( double* ) * m );       // allocate the memory for (m) double*

     (*a)[0] = malloc( sizeof(double) * n * m ); // allocate the linearized memory for (n*m) double

     for( int i=1; i<m; i++ )
         (*a)[i] = (*a)[0] + n*i;                // initialize the pointers for rows [1, m[
}
```

I think this would be more comprehensible:

```
void alloc2d(double*** a, int m, int n) {

     double **temp = malloc( sizeof( double* ) * m ); // allocate the memory for (m) double*

     temp[0] = malloc( sizeof(double) * n * m );      // allocate the linearized memory for (n*m) double
     for ( int i=1; i<m; i++ )
         temp[i] = temp[0] + n*i;                     // initialize the pointers for rows [1, m[

     *a = temp;                                       // assign dynamic memory pointer to output parameter
}
```