# Matrix addition in c using malloc not allowing full input

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

So my assignment is to add matrices (they don't have to  be square but the two matrices will always be the same size) by dynamically allocating the space for a 2-D array, and I used a double pointer. My function to get the user-inputted matrices is as follows:

```
void matrixEntry(const int rowNum, const int colNum, const char 
matrixNum, int** matrix) {
  int i, j, k;

  matrix = (int**) malloc(rowNum * sizeof(int*));

  for (k = 0; k < rowNum; ++k) {
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(colNum * sizeof(int));
  }

  printf("Enter Matrix %c\n", matrixNum);

  for (i = 0; i < rowNum; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < colNum; ++j) {
      scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

where I call it in main twice as such:

```
  matrixEntry(rowNum, colNum, matA, matrixOne);
  matrixEntry(rowNum, colNum, matB, matrixTwo);
```

However, when I run the program I'm only allowed to enter the first row of Matrix A before the program stops running. I think this is because I didn't allocate enough space for the 2nd row, but I'm not sure where my mistake is. My thought process when allocating the space was that

```
matrix = (int**) malloc(rowNum * sizeof(int*));
```

allocated the space for the rowNum number of rows, and then the for loop allocated the space for the number of columns. Is this correct?

Comment: `matrix[i]` -> `matrix[k]`?

Comment: Turn on warnings.  The compiler should complain about uninitialized variable usage.  It really makes me angry when teachers don't start with this.  Without warnings, coding gets much more difficult.

Comment: While this is not really related to your problem, casting the result of `malloc` is frowned upon in C.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons so what would the acceptable version of that be?

Comment: `matrix = malloc(rowNum * sizeof *matrix);` and `matrix[k] = malloc(colNum * sizeof **matrix);` are my preferences.

Comment: @Ismael you would just not cast the results.  No frills needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing a triple pointer into function then mallocing a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116623/passing-a-triple-pointer-into-function-then-mallocing-a-2d-array)

Comment: @mch Note concerning `malloc(rowNum * sizeof *matrix);`, when the parameters to the multiplication may use `int` and more than 2 exist, I have found putting `sizeof` first as in `malloc(sizeof *matrix * r * c);` better than `malloc(r * c * sizeof *matrix);` as the first insures the `* r` and  `* c` are done using `size_t` math versus `int math`.  Useful for large allocations.  So I following this even with `malloc(sizeof *matrix * rowNum);`

Comment: The function overwrites the argument `int** matrix` passed to it with `matrix = (int**) malloc(rowNum * sizeof(int*));` and this is discarded at function return, resulting in a memory leak and nothing visible from outside of the function.

Comment: @chux: The proper way would be to use the correct type `size_t` for the variables, too. But yes, it is more common to have the base-type as the first operand.

Comment: Sidenote: don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends. Or, in general: never use an unnecessary cast or one you don't understand.